# Inherit onclick in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following Button component and the main file.

I want to be able to set "onclick" on the main file while keeping the original onclick behavior.

So in the following example, by clicking the button for now it does console.log "animated." only, but the desired result is "animated." and "clicked". (or vice versa)

Is it possible? Thanks.

```js
// Button.jsx 
export default function Button(props) {

    function animate(e) {
        console.log("animated.");
        // 
    }

    return (
        <button
            {...props}
            ref={button}
            onClick={e => {
                animate(e);
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </button>
    );
}
```

```js
// main.js 
import Button from "./Button.jsx"

.. 

<Button onClick={(e) => console.log("clicked.")}>
    Text
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call the `onClick` from the `props` so that both gets executed.

```jsx
export default function Button(props) {

    function animate(e) {
        console.log("animated.");
        // 
    }

    return (
        <button
            {...props}
            ref={button}
            onClick={e => {
                animate(e);
                if(props.onClick) props.onClick(e);
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </button>
    );
}
```

**Edit:** as suggested in comment, you can also use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead of `if` statement.

Comment: Can be shortened to remove the if statement, instead using optional chaining `props.onClick?.(e)`